# Unhandled exception in ReferenceReturn.exe:

Tags: c++

Please take a look at this simple code:

```
// A.h
#pragma once

#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    A();
    ~A();

    int a;

private:

};

A::A() :a{3}
{
}

A::~A()
{
    std::cout << 42 << std::endl;
}
```

In Main.cpp I have a global function:

```
// Main.cpp
#include "A.h"

A GlobalGetAByValue(){
    static A a{};
    return a;
}

int main(){
    A a = GlobalGetAByValue();

    int val;
    std::cin >> val;

    return 0;
}
```

And now interesting - if in close a console with close button I have an exception in A's destructor. If I enter some values and press enter - console closes without exception. If I initialize variable **a** as local variable or if I create a pointer with **new** keyword and delete it just before return everything works fine.

So I only get this **cout** error in destructor when I'm using static A. But why?

Comment: What does the exception say?

Comment: i think it's a common mistake, one of such is mentioned here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IY18398

Comment: The full compiler message is "Unhandled exception at 0x0F5604A9 (msvcp120d.dll) in ReferenceReturn.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFEEEFEEE."
Windows 7, VS2013 Pro Update3

Comment: Very roughly speaking, forcibly closing the console window (or pressing Ctrl-C) puts the program into an abnormal and potentially inconsistent state, and weird things can happen as a result.

Comment: Well, that's explains ). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As it said in section 3.6.3 "Termination" of the C++03 standard:

"Destructors for initialized objects of static storage duration (declared at block scope or at namespace scope) are called as a result of returning from main and as a result of calling exit."

so, i can make a suggestion, that when destructor called, there no any valid ostream object (like cout in this case).

Comment: Yeah, but it works if I fill my variable in cin and press enter. In that case I can see output from destructor for a moment while console not closed.

Comment: so, i can continue my suggestions by statement, that if there are no any stream object using in main, iostream isn't initialized, and referencing to cout in destructor cause to fail.

Comment: Sorry, but what does it mean - "if there are no any stream object using in main, iostream isn't initialized"? There's a call to std::cin. And I've tried to put std::cout in main and had the same error.

Comment: honestly, i don't know, what that mean. But, when i look at some realisation of iostream.cpp, i find there code like this:

void  _STLP_CALL ios_base::_S_initialize() {
...
  _STLP_TRY {
    istream* ptr_cin  = new(static_cast<void*>(&cin))  istream(0);
    ofstream* ptr_cout = new(static_cast<void*>(&cout)) ofstream;
...

i don't know, when initialize method called, theoretically it can be called, when the first using of cout/cin/smth else in main occured. 

Again, it's just my suggestion.